# Charles Proxy not working when using virtual device

Tags: proxy, charles-proxy, mitmproxy

So I bought a macbook some time ago and found out I could run some iOS apps with the M1 chip and I could use charles proxy to be able to intercept the requests. So I figured Windows can do the same with the android subsystem and I gave it a go, turn out I am not able to do that. Everything is installed correctly and the certificate is in the right place and charles works on every other app on my PC.

For some reason no requests seem to be going through the charles proxy app when I do them from an android app install into the subsystem. Thought I would put a post here since it is something I am not familiar with and people here likely know more than me.

From my little knowledge about this I would assume it has something to do with the way the app is being ran in the virtual device, I am guessing Windows is seeing it as a new device hence charles cannot pickup the requests.

Comment: By default Android apps ignore user installed certificates since Android 11 (AFAIR). You need a rooted device or modify the app you want to intercept traffic of.